# junk(Null) char appending to Actual snowflake table data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am performing some couple of transformations before writing pyspark dataframe to snowflakes table. I have written Snowflake write in below way.

`df.spark.format("snoflake").opton(**loginOptions).option("dtable", SF_table).mode("append").save()`

It is working fine for the other records. But for this particular data point Some junk char(Null) is appending to the data.

**Action performed on this col:**

1. Trimming the data as we are getting the empty string sometimes. (Ex:    "data"   )
2. Casting to string before loading to snowflake

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That character ASCII NUL char(0)

You can replace that using '\0' replaced with ''

```
with data as (select '\0Record1' col1
union 
select '\0Record2'
)
select  replace(col1,'\0','') from data
```

Comment: Replace works.... In the first place there is No Null in the Data, Even I am stripping the Column before loading in to the snowflake. Any idea why its coming in Snowflakes..? @aditya-pawar

Comment: Not sure, Unless I have access to data and to debugging, I don't think I have definite answer. But as you mentioned it's just for specific rows, I don't see issue with process, It must be at source. Try 1) Loading pyspark without transformation, and verify. 2) Export these specific rows from source to flat and open that in notepad++, enable show all characters, if NUL is there you can see it

Comment: Yeah I its coming from source itself. ThankYou